# how to make to android apps communicate (when they are on the same wifi network)

Tags: java, android, networking, communication

I'm trying to make two android apps communicate , with simple passing of data from one app to another. I have tried bluetooth but it's way too tough for somebody like me. is there a way i can make apps communicate with each other like regular java apps? if they are on the same network?

Comment: Multicasting is available and ServerSocket and Socket classes should work the same way that they work on standard Java stand-alone applications if that is an approach that you would like to go down.

Comment: [**Sockets**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) are well supported on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Sockets**

[UDP Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html)

[TCP Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)